# Get row data in extjs on cell edit

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am creating a Extjs grid. In which most of the column is editable. what i need is if user change any column value on blur of that i will call my method do some calculation based on other column value.and replace the column value with calculated values.code is here.

```
var incomeTaxOverrideModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([{
    id : 'fromDate',
    header : "From Date",
    dataIndex : 'fromDate',
    width : 80,
    renderer : drenderer,
    editor : this.fromDateEditor
}, {
    id : 'toDate',
    header : "To Date",
    dataIndex : 'toDate',
    width : 80,
    renderer : drenderer,
    editor : this.toDateEditor
}, {
    id : 'rawTax',
    header : "Raw Tax",
    dataIndex : 'rawTax',
    width : 80,
    align : 'right',
    selectOnFocus : true,
    editor : new Ext.form.NumberField({"blur":this.calculateTaxForword}),
    renderer : Gts.payItemRenderer()
}, {
    id : 'surcharge',
    header : "Surcharge",
    dataIndex : 'surcharge',
    width : 80,
    align : 'right',
    selectOnFocus : true,
    editor : new Ext.form.NumberField({}),
    renderer : Gts.payItemRenderer()
}, {
    id : 'cess',
    header : "Cess",
    dataIndex : 'cess',
    width : 80,
    align : 'right',
    selectOnFocus : true,
    editor : new Ext.form.NumberField({}),
    renderer : Gts.payItemRenderer()
}, {
    id : 'totalTax',
    header : "Total Tax",
    dataIndex : 'totalTax',
    width : 80,
    align : 'right',
    selectOnFocus : true,
    editor : new Ext.form.NumberField({}),
    renderer : Gts.payItemRenderer()
}, {
    id : 'taxAmount',
    header : "Taxable Income",
    dataIndex : 'taxAmount',
    width : 100,
    align : 'right',
    selectOnFocus : true,
    editor : new Ext.form.NumberField({}),
    renderer : Gts.payItemRenderer()
}, {
    id : 'remarks',
    header : "Remarks",
    dataIndex : 'remarks',
    width : 250,
    editor : new Ext.form.TextField({})
}, {
    id : 'modifiedDate',
    header : "Modified On",
    dataIndex : 'modifiedDate',
    width : 100,
    renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d M Y h:i:s A'),
    width : 150
}

]);

this.itoGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store : this.itoStore,
    cm : incomeTaxOverrideModel,
    autoExpandColumn : 'remarks',
    autoScroll : true,
    containerScroll : true,
    frame : false,
    stripeRows : true,
    width : 830,
    height : 233,
    clicksToEdit : 1,
    layout : 'fit',
    loadMask : true,
    tbar : [this.addAction, this.deleteAction],
    trackMouseOver : true
});
```

i created on method

```
calculateTaxForword :function(){
    console.log(this.itoGrid) 
    //console.log(this.itoGrid.getStore().getModifiedRecords())
}
```

but its not coming anything.i have to calculate value based on raw tax.surcharge and cess so i need all the value in my method.how to do this any one please help

Answer (score 5):

The `CellEditing` plugin has a `beforeedit` event that you can listen to:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit

This will give you access to things like:

```
Parameters
editor : Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing
e : Object
An edit event with the following properties:

grid - The grid
record - The record being edited
field - The field name being edited
value - The value for the field being edited.
row - The grid table row
column - The grid Column defining the column that is being edited.
rowIdx - The row index that is being edited
colIdx - The column index that is being edited
cancel - Set this to true to cancel the edit or return false from your handler.
eOpts : Object - The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener.
```

Answer (score 0):

Each column object has `editingPlugin.activeRecord` property with record itself.